# Controller Action get called repeatedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am using Razor WebGrid and my controller action is getting repeatedly called when click on sort by header or click on page links. First time it is getting called only once but next time onwards it is getting called repeatedly. Please can anyone help.

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string sort = "GridName", string sortDir = "ASC")
        {

            const int pageSize    = 5;
            string successMessage = string.Empty;
            var message           = string.Empty;
            int pageIndex1        = page - 1;


            if (RenderFirstTime == 1) 
            {
                GridCRUDCollection.UpdateGridModelCollection(null, pageSize, pageIndex1, sort, sortDir);
                RenderFirstTime = 0;
                return View(GridCRUDCollection);
            }
            else
            {
                GridCRUDCollection.UpdateGridModelCollection(null, pageSize, pageIndex1, sort, sortDir);
                return PartialView("GridDetailsView", GridCRUDCollection);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's happened to me at times because of placing a script file in a partial view.. make sure you can download a script multiple times..

Comment: Thanks Lewis. I removed the script files from partial view class but still rendering the grid which is a partial view one after another, by repeatedly calling the action in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code with an `<img src="#" ... >` is what did it for me. Once I removed the #'s the controller got called just once. The grid may be generating those and populating them later via Javascript. One way to diagnose it is to use LabJS to prevent immediate execution.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the # in the src did not work for me. This issue is related to Ajax call. Substitute Ajax call with normal querystring from UI